# Maximum value of arg z

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

On a sketch of an Argand diagram, shade the region whose points represent complex numbers satisfying the inequalities $|z-2-i|\leq1$ and $|z-i|\leq|z-2|$. Calculate the maximum value of arg $z$ for points lying in the shaded region.

I've already sketched the diagram. Can anyone explain how to find the maximum value with an aid of diagram? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$|z-2-i|\le 1$ is the disk centre $2+i$ radius 1. $|z-i|\le |z-2|$ is the half-plane to the left of the perpendicular bisector of the line joining the points 2 and $i$. We want the point in the intersection of these two regions which has the largest arg. That is obviously $X$ where $OX$ is tangent to the circle.

We have $\arg z=2\arg(2+i)=2\tan^{-1}0.5$.

Comment: Can I ask which software you've used to graph?

Comment: Geometer's Sketchpad. It is not really graphing software. It is mainly used for Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Why is 2arg(2+i)?

Comment: Call the $z=2$ the point $Y$. Then we have $\angle COY=\angle COX$.